# Jest tests hanging even after running server.close() on my express app

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I have an express app which I need to start on my integration test case.

The express app is exported in the `app.js` file **without listening to any port**. So, my test case goes like this:

```
const app = require('../src/app');

describe('Pact Verification', () => {
  const port = 3002;
  let server;

  beforeAll(done => {
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen({ port }, done)
  });

  afterAll(done => {
    server.close(done);
  });

  it(....
```

The problem is, once the test is ran with `Jest`, it hangs. I have to either `--forceExit` or `^C` to exit.

I even updated to Jest 23 to use [--detectOpenHandles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#detectopenhandles) but I don't see any output in the terminal, it keeps hanging so that's not helping either.

Since the exported `app` **is not listening to any port**, and **it doesn't have any database connections or such**, the problem is unlikely to be there, maybe its in my `beforeAll`/`afterAll` block. What am I missing?

### Update 1

Here is the content of my `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
}
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/v1/', indexRouter); // <-- these endpoints just return faker data in JSON format (https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const { status, message } = err;

  const stack = status !== 404 && err.stack || undefined;

  res.status(status || 500)
    .json({
      message,
      stack,
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing what your `../src/app` file looks like.

Comment: Basic express skeleton, but I'll post it, just a second

Comment: @VtoCorleone there you go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `server` is `undefined` in `afterAll` because it's assigned in another scope as `const server = http.createServer(app)`. Instead, it should be:

```
server = http.createServer(app);
```

There should be an exception, so `done` is never get called in `afterAll`. Currently Jest suppresses errors from `afterAll`, there's Jest [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6692) that addresses `afterAll` bug.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this. Good catch!